# How to save huge nested array book locally (in json file) in swiftUI/swift from server?

Tags: ios, json, swift

(fyi Note:The app has been made in swift wireframe but now swiftUI has been added through hostview to handle complex structure and load data easily*).

**What i want to do**:  when registered user clicks on notification button, it shows the small tableview on top right corner where updates from the discussion forum and new books uploaded from server are notified.. Now i want to save the book offline in json format(through document directory if possible) when user clicks on specific book that was shown in the notification. below is the notification area where updates are shown after clicking on notification bell[image]

and then it shows like this [image]

now when the user clicks on tableview cell("book was newly added"), the book should be saved offline in json format.. i want to load that file later in swift structure that is created to handle the data in swiftUI.

the data that comes from the api is in array form(huge nested data). every time the unique user logs in , it takes the user token to show the notification. Below is the API manager class..

i'm, providing link as the character count is beyond S.O limit..
https://github.com/JigarDave102/APImanager.git

**What i tried and don't know how to take next step after this:**

```html
struct GetBookResponse: Codable {
    var message:String
    var totalRecord:Int
    var totalPage:Int
    var nextPage:String
    var books:[GetBook]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case message
        case totalRecord
        case totalPage
        case nextPage
        case books = "data"
    }
    
}

struct GetBook: Codable {
    var bookId: Int
    var title: String
    var content: String
    var coverImage: String
    
    enum CoddingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case bookId = "iBookId"
        case title = "vTitle"
        case content = "txContent"
        case coverImage = "txCoverImage"
    }
}
```

*and api example for one book: book_id can be used from anyone from following 58,77,76,75,73,58

http://vadtaldhambooks.com/api/v1/get_book?book_id=58*

*data to save to local json, fetch from* : txContent

and notification class

```
import UIKit
import PKHUD
import Alamofire
import EmptyDataSet_Swift

class NotificationsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var notifications: NotificationsResponse?
    var currentPage = 1
    var totalPage = 0
    
    var aryOfNotificationList = NSMutableArray()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        title = _appDelegate.getLocalize("kNotifications")
        
        //        tableView.emptyDataSetSource = self
        //        tableView.emptyDataSetDelegate = self
        
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        
        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
        
        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        //self.getNotifications(page: "\(currentPage)")
        self.fetchNotificationList(page: currentPage)
    }
    
    
    
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.aryOfNotificationList.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "notificationCell", for: indexPath) as! NotificationTableViewCell
                
        let json = self.aryOfNotificationList.object(at: indexPath.row)as! NSDictionary

        if let str = json.value(forKey: "vTitle")as? String{
            cell.titleLable.text = str
        }
        if let str = json.value(forKey: "vText")as? String{
            cell.detailLable.text = str
        }
        if let str = json.value(forKey: "tCreatedAt")as? Int{
            cell.datLabel.text = getDate(unixdate: str, timezone: "UTC")
        }
     
        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let json = self.aryOfNotificationList.object(at: indexPath.row)as! NSDictionary
        if let dic = json.value(forKey: "txParameters")as? NSDictionary{
            if let str = dic.value(forKey: "iBookId")as? Int{
                getBookService(bookId: str)
            }
        }
    }
    
}


extension NotificationsTableViewController: EmptyDataSetSource {
    func title(forEmptyDataSet scrollView: UIScrollView) -> NSAttributedString? {
        guard let font = UIFont(name: "NotoSansGujarati", size: 18) else {
            // do something with attributes
            return NSAttributedString(string: "Record not found.")
            
        }
        
        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.secondaryColor]
        
        return NSAttributedString(string: "Record not found.", attributes: attributes)
    }
}

// MARK:- API
extension NotificationsTableViewController {
    
    func fetchNotificationList(page:Int){
        guard let urlEncodedString = (AppConstants.URL.getNotifications + "?pageno=\(page)").addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else {
            return
        }
        HUD.show(.progress)
        let url = URL(string: urlEncodedString)!
        print(url)
        
        var headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Content-Type"  : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Accept"        : "application/json",
        ]
        
        if let accessToken = User.current?.accessToken {
            headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer \(accessToken)"
        } else if let accessToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "AccessToken") {
            headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer \(accessToken)"
        }
        
        AF.request(urlEncodedString, method:.get, parameters:nil, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    if let json = value as? NSDictionary{
                        print(json)
                        if let str = json.value(forKey: "totalRecord")as? Int{
                            self.totalPage = str
                        }
                        if let ary = json.value(forKey: "data")as? NSArray{
                            for j in ary{
                                self.aryOfNotificationList.add(j as! NSDictionary)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if self.currentPage >= self.totalPage{
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            HUD.hide()
                            self.tableView.delegate = self
                            self.tableView.dataSource = self
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }else{
                        self.currentPage = self.currentPage + 1
                        self.fetchNotificationList(page: self.currentPage)
                    }
                    
                    
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        HUD.hide()
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    
    func getBookService(bookId: Int) {
        guard let urlEncodedString = (AppConstants.URL.getBook + "?book_id=\(bookId)").addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else {
            return
        }
        HUD.show(.progress)
        let url = URL(string: urlEncodedString)!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                HUD.hide()
            }
            if let er = error {
                print(er)
                Utils.showAlertController(with: er.localizedDescription, viewController: self!)
                return
            }
            guard let unwrappedData = data else { return }
            do {
                //print(String(data: unwrappedData, encoding: .utf8))
                let getBooksResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(GetBookResponse.self, from: unwrappedData)
                guard getBooksResponse.books.count != 0 else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        Utils.showAlertController(with: "No book found.", viewController: self!)
                    }
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    for book in getBooksResponse.books {
                        var bookJson =
                            """
                        "id": \(book.bookId),
                        "title": \(book.title),
                        "desc": \(book.content)
                        """
                        _appDelegate.loadString(jsonString: &bookJson, type: .Book, langType: .Gujrati)
                    }
                    
                    Utils.showAlertController(with: "Book is saved", viewController: self!)
                    
                }
            } catch {
                print("json error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        
    }
    
    func getDate(unixdate: Int, timezone: String) -> String {
        let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(unixdate))
        let dayTimePeriodFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dayTimePeriodFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY"
        dayTimePeriodFormatter.timeZone = (NSTimeZone(name: timezone)! as TimeZone)
        let dateString = dayTimePeriodFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
        return "\(dateString)"
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking about, you talk about saving json locally but then you say that there is an error loading data so which one is it? And if you have any error you need help with then that error should be included in the question.

Comment: And what is your problem with doing this?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far in saving data to a local file. Also the link you provide does not work.

Comment: there are already local files stored using Coredata. But i don't want to get into complex part (that hanged my tableview). i want to create class that too using document directory to save json. While there seems to be many questions regarding local json, none, seems to be relevant to my specific case as "huge data specifically in array". Also github link provided works fine.

Comment: currently following below method tutorial to implement 'save json':
https://medium.com/@lkleung0531/ios-how-to-read-and-update-local-json-file-with-tableview-1b6c2a49e7b4

Comment: the github link provided does not work, it may be private not public. So basically your question is, how to write to a file, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code to download the book data from your server at:
"http://vadtaldhambooks.com/api/v1/get_book?book_id=58"
, and store it into a local file "testbookfile",
as a array of books. The code takes into consideration some of your previous questions/answers
and shows how to decode into an array of books the unusual json from the api, where the book
content `txContent` is a string (where it should be an array of book content).

Run the code with `fetchData()` in the `DataModel`, then click the "Save to file button" to save the data into a
local file called "testbookfile". Then comment out the `fetchData()` and use the `loadFromFile()` instead.

Since the call to the server is "http" instead of the required "https", you need to temporarily set your `Info.plist`
with:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</dict>
```

The code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}  

// holds the books and functions to fetch and save them
class DataModel: ObservableObject, @unchecked Sendable {
    @Published var books: [Book] = []
    @Published var loading = false
    
    let fileName = "testbookfile"
    let urlString = "http://vadtaldhambooks.com/api/v1/get_book?book_id=58"
    
    init() {
         fetchData()  // <-- to fetch the data from the server at urlString
        // loadFromFile()  // <-- get the data from local file, after it has been saved
    }
    
    func fetchData() {
        Task {
            let res: BookResponse? = await fetch()
            if let response = res {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.books = response.books
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // todo deal with errors
    private func fetch<T: Decodable>() async -> T? {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            do {
                let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: URLRequest(url: url))
                let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                return results
            }
            catch {
                print("error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    func loadFromFile() {
        do {
            let furl = try FileManager.default
                .url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
                .appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                .appendingPathExtension("json")
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: furl)
            let theBooks = try JSONDecoder().decode([Book].self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.books = theBooks
            }
        } catch {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func saveToFile() {
        do {
            let furl = try FileManager.default
                .url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
                .appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                .appendingPathExtension("json")
            print("---> writing file to: \(furl)")
            let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(books)
            try data.write(to: furl)
        } catch {
            print("---> error saveToFile: \(error)")
        }
    }

}

extension View {

    func attString(_ str: String) -> AttributedString {
        attributedString(from: str, font: Font.system(size: 22))
    }

    func attributedString(from str: String, font: Font) -> AttributedString {
        if let theData = str.data(using: .utf16) {
            do {
                let theString = try NSAttributedString(data: theData, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
                var attaString = AttributedString(theString)
                attaString.font = font
                attaString.backgroundColor = .yellow
                return attaString
            } catch {
                print("\(error)")
            }
        }
        return AttributedString(str)
    }

}

struct BookView: View {
    @State var bookContent: BookContent

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text(attString(bookContent.title))
        }.background(Color.yellow)
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var dataModel = DataModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 22) {
                ForEach(dataModel.books) { book in
                    ScrollView {
                        LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 22) {
                            Section(header: Text(book.title).font(.largeTitle).fontWeight(.heavy).foregroundColor(.yellow).padding(10)) {
                                ForEach(book.content) { bookContent in
                                    OutlineGroup(bookContent.child ?? [], children: \.child) { item in
                                        NavigationLink(destination: BookView(bookContent: item)) {
                                            Text(bookContent.title).fontWeight(.heavy)
                                        }.padding(10)
                                    }
                                }
                            }.onAppear { dataModel.loading = false }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // remove the toolbar, after the data has been saved to file
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    VStack {
                        if dataModel.loading {
                            ProgressView("Loading data …")
                        } else {
                            Button("Save to file") {
                                dataModel.saveToFile()
                            }
                            .padding(20)
                            .buttonStyle(BorderedButtonStyle())
                        }
                    }.padding(.top, 20)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Book list")
        }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
            .onAppear { dataModel.loading = true }
    }
    
}

struct BookResponse: Codable, Sendable {
    var message: String = ""
    var totalRecord: Int = 0
    var totalPage: Int = 0
    var nextPage: String = ""
    var books: [Book] = []
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case message
        case totalRecord
        case totalPage
        case nextPage
        case books = "data"
    }
}

struct Book: Identifiable, Codable, Sendable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    var bookId: Int
    var title: String
    var content: [BookContent] = []
    var coverImage: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case bookId = "iBookId"
        case title = "vTitle"
        case content = "txContent"
        case coverImage = "txCoverImage"
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        bookId = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .bookId)
        title = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        coverImage = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .coverImage)
        // decode the book content, when it comes as a String
        if let theString = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .content) {
            if let data = theString.data(using: .utf16) {
                do {
                    content = try JSONDecoder().decode([BookContent].self, from: data)
                } catch {
                    print("----> Book content decoding error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        } else {
            content = try values.decode([BookContent].self, forKey: .content)
        }
    }
    
}

struct BookContent: Identifiable, Codable, Sendable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    var title, type: String
    var child: [BookContent]?
}
```